# notificiation too short

Tags: samsung, notifications, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S8+.
When a new notification appears on the lock screen,
it appears within 2~3 seconds which I think is too short.
Can I change the time it remains on the lock screen?

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about notifications, not toasts? Notifications usually remain until you dismiss them. Toasts disappear without user intervention in the time setup by the corresponding dev. For explanations, please see: [Popups, dialogs, notifications, toasts: what's the difference?](/q/52789/16575)

Comment: @Izzy Maybe I used a wrong term. It is correct that notification remains. But the thing I saw is certainly different from toasts. It contains preview contents of a messaging app and usually appears in the middle of the screen rather than at the bottom.

Comment: Though toasts *most usually* appear at the bottom, they *can* be positioned almost everywhere. But the "preview contents" IMHO rule them out indeed. Leaves the possibility an app removes its own notification. So does that happen for *all* notifications, or just for those specific to some app?

Comment: @Izzy It applies to  all apps that shows such kind of notification (or popup or ttoast).

Comment: As absurd as the question is, a screenshot would be helpful (absurd as it's most likely hard to be fast enough), so we can for sure tell what it is. Also, just for clarification: that's only affecting the lock screen (i.e. not a case if the device is unlocked)? And once it's "gone", is it available from the notification area if you swipe it down?

Comment: @Izzy Now I got what it is called. I think it is called 'pop-up preview'